# Merge repo git svn clone with other git repo

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

For years my team has been using SVN.
A few months ago we switched to Git by doing a simple push of an SVN branch, without the history and continued to develop on Git.
Today we need to get the SVN history back before it is lost.
So I used git svn clone to turn SVN into Git.

So I end up with a SVN project, are equivalent in Git project (proj_with_history) and a Git project having the same initial commit as the last commit of one of the branches (proj_without_history) of the proj_with_history.

The question is, how do you link/merge the proj_with_history with the proj_without_history, knowing that new branches and tags have been created on proj_without_history ?

If possible, we would like to make this migration transparent in the graph of the commits, even if the history is rewritten, as long as conflicts are avoided.

- proj_with_history : ... - f30ab - 98ca9
- proj_without_history : 34ac2 - h20a5 - ...
- 98ca9 and 34ac2 have the same code

Comment: What is "proj_without_history"?

Comment: The branch that they started _without_ svn history. Just a single commit with the last content from an svn branch and then started working on git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch the svn clone into a repo with your git history, graft the root of that git history on to the converted svn commit its content came from (`git replace --graft $theroot $theoriginaltip`), vet the result locally, then bake in the graft with `git filter-branch`, the brute-force just-do-it version is `git filter-branch -- --all --tag-name-filter cat` to completely abandon the old history and replace it with the new tips with the extended history.

Comment: Now, this is something I need to learn about. Great tip!